# Load component on button click and pass data to it

Tags: react-native

I have a card and I want to show a new `component` when the card is clicked and pass the data of clicked card to that new component. When I click on the card, nothing happens and it does not even throw the error on console.

Here is the component I want show on click:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import App from './App'

class NewsDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
  }
}

export default NewsDetail
```

And Here is my card:

```
showDetails = () => {
    return <NewsDetail/>
  }

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea
        className={classes.cardActionsArea}
        onClick={() => showDetails()}>
        <CardMedia component="img" height="140" image={checkedImgUrl(imgUrl)} />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h6">
            {newsTitle}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {newsSummary}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        <Typography className={classes.toLocalTime} variant="caption" color="primary" component="p">
          {toLocalTime(publishedAt)}
        </Typography>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => openArticleUrl(articleUrl)}>
          {sourceName}
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will go with router flux to load the view page desired

Comment: Can you please give me any example or something?

Comment: What actually are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to load a different component on button click and pass some data to that component.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like `react-navigation` to navigate between components (screens).
check if you want the [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

alright so if you want to show the component on the route where the card is on. you could just do hide/show with the component. so here what I would do is take a value in state and change its value to true or false according to the display

```
`const [displayStatus, setDisplayStatus] = useState(false)`
`
<div>
<Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea
        className={classes.cardActionsArea}
        onClick={() => setDisplayStatus(true)}>
        <CardMedia component="img" height="140" image={checkedImgUrl(imgUrl)} />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h6">
            {newsTitle}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {newsSummary}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        <Typography className={classes.toLocalTime} variant="caption" color="primary" component="p">
          {toLocalTime(publishedAt)}
        </Typography>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => openArticleUrl(articleUrl)}>
          {sourceName}
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
{
displayStatus && <NewsDetail/>
}
</div>
`
```

Comment: I don't want to show/hide the component on the same route. I want to load a new component on button click.

Comment: then what you can do is where I have put the <NewsDetails /> component. replace it with your function. `showDetails()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, conceptually it is not the best way to do what you want.

1. You don't want to pass arrow func to Card's `onClick`.
2. Instead of that, define a method like `onCardClick`,  where you would do `this.setState({ isNewsDetailsVisible: true })`
3. Then you can write something like `this.state.isNewsDetailsVisible && <NewsDetails />` in your Card's `render` method.  The better approach would be define a method `renderNewsDetails` and inside of it check for state value.

Then, if you want to understand current behavior, you just returning JSX form `onClick` handler - you can't render anything with this structure. If you want something to be displayed, you need to put it in the render method directly or through the methods like `renderSomeContent`.

Then, if we assume that we have a lot of cards and want  to pass it's data somewhere, you need to understand where you would need that data. If it needs to be available in child component, you can pass it through props. If it's parent component, then you can pass to your `Card` component some handler like `onCardClick` wich would accept some `data` argument.